# Rust and C linking problems with minimal program and no_std

Tags: c, linker, rust

I'm trying to build a minimal program in C that calls Rust functions, preferably compiled with `#![no_std]`, in Windows, using GCC 6.1.0 and `rustc 1.11.0-nightly (bb4a79b08 2016-06-15) x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`. Here's what I tried first:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int, int);

int main()
{
    printf("Sum is %d.\n", sum(2, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

**sum.rs**

```
#![no_std]
#![feature(libc)]
extern crate libc;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn sum(x: libc::c_int, y: libc::c_int) -> libc::c_int
{
    x + y
}
```

Then I tried running:

```
rustc --crate-type=staticlib --emit=obj sum.rs
```

But got:

```
error: language item required, but not found: `panic_fmt`
error: language item required, but not found: `eh_personality`
error: language item required, but not found: `eh_unwind_resume`
error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

OK, so some of those errors are related to panic unwinding. I found out about a Rust compiler setting to remove unwinding support, `-C panic=abort`. Using that, the errors about `eh_personality` and `eh_unwind_resume` disappeared, but Rust still required the `panic_fmt` function. So I found its signature at [the Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/panicking/fn.panic_fmt.html), then I added that to the file:

**sum.rs**

```
#![no_std]
#![feature(lang_items, libc)]
extern crate libc;

#[lang = "panic_fmt"]
pub fn panic_fmt(_fmt: core::fmt::Arguments, _file_line: &(&'static str, u32)) -> !
    { loop { } }

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn sum(x: libc::c_int, y: libc::c_int) -> libc::c_int
{
    x + y
}
```

Then, I tried building the whole program again:

```
rustc --crate-type=staticlib --emit=obj -C panic=abort sum.rs
gcc -c main.c
gcc sum.o main.o -o program.exe
```

But got:

```
sum.o:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `core::panicking::panic::h907815f47e914305'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The panic function reference is probably from a overflow check in the addition at `sum()`. That's all fine and desirable. According to [this page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/panicking/index.html), I need to define my own panic function to work with libcore. But I can't find instructions on how to do so: the function for which I am supposed to provide a definition is called `panic_impl` in the docs, however the linker is complaining about `panic::h907815f47e914305`, whatever that's supposed to be.

Using `objdump`, I was able to find the missing function's name, and hacked that into C:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sum(int, int);

void _ZN4core9panicking5panic17h907815f47e914305E()
{
    printf("Panic!\n");
    abort();
}

int main()
{
    printf("Sum is %d.\n", sum(2, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the whole program compiles and links successfully, and even works correctly.

If I then try using arrays in Rust, another kind of panic function (for bounds checks) is generated, so I need to provide a definition for that too. Whenever I try something more complex in Rust, new errors arise. And, by the way, `panic_fmt` seems to never be called, even when a panic does happen.

Anyways, this all seems very unreliable, and contradicts every information I could find via Google on the matter. There's [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3kjjhz/linker_error_while_crosscompiling_with_no_std/), but I tried to follow the instructions to no avail.

It seems such a simple and fundamental thing, but I can't get it to work the right way. Perhaps it's a Rust nightly bug? But I need `libc` and `lang_items`. How can I generate a Rust object file/static library without unwinding or panic support? It should probably just execute an illegal processor instruction when it wants to panic, or call a panic function I can safely define in C.

Comment: Please do not edit your **question** to include an **answer**. Stack Overflow explicitly encourages you to add your own answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use `--emit=obj`; just `rustc --crate-type=staticlib -C panic=abort sum.rs` should do the right thing.  (This fixes the _ZN4core9panicking5panic17h907815f47e914305E link error.)

To fix another link error, you need to write panic_fmt correctly (note the use of `extern`):

```
#[lang="panic_fmt"]
extern fn panic_fmt(_: ::core::fmt::Arguments, _: &'static str, _: u32) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

With those changes, everything appears to work the way it's supposed to.

---

You need panic_fmt so you can decide what to do when a panic happens: if you use `#![no_std]`, rustc assumes there is no standard library/libc/kernel, so it can't just call abort() or expect an illegal instruction to do anything useful.  It's something which should be exposed in stable Rust somehow, but I don't know if anyone is working on stabilizing it.

You don't need to use `#![feature(libc)]` to get libc; you should use the version posted on crates.io instead (or you can declare the functions you need by hand).

Comment: error[E0433]: failed to resolve: maybe a missing crate `core`?
  --> lib.rs:13:26
   |
13 | extern fn panic_fmt(_: ::core::fmt::Arguments, _: &'static str, _: u32) -> !
   |                          ^^^^ maybe a missing crate `core`?
[...]
Some errors have detailed explanations: E0433, E0522, E0658.

Answer (score 4):

So, the solution, from the accepted answer, was:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sum(int, int);

void panic(const char* filename_unterminated, int filename_size, int line_num)
{
    printf("Panic! At line %d, file ", line_num);

    for (int i = 0; i < filename_size; i++)
        printf("%c", filename_unterminated[i]);

    abort();
}

int main()
{
    // Sum as u8 will overflow to test panicking.
    printf("Sum is %d.\n", sum(0xff, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

**sum.rs**

```
#![no_std]
#![feature(lang_items, libc)]
extern crate libc;

extern "C"
{
    fn panic(
        filename_unterminated: *const libc::c_char,
        filename_size: libc::c_int,
        line_num: libc::c_int) -> !;
}

#[lang="panic_fmt"]
extern fn panic_fmt(_: ::core::fmt::Arguments, filename: &'static str, line_num: u32) -> !
{
    unsafe { panic(filename.as_ptr() as _, filename.len() as _, line_num as _); }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn sum(x: libc::c_int, y: libc::c_int) -> libc::c_int
{
    // Convert to u8 to test overflow panicking.
    ((x as u8) + (y as u8)) as _
}
```

And compiling with:

```
rustc --crate-type=staticlib -C panic=abort sum.rs
gcc -c main.c
gcc main.o -L . -l sum -o program.exe
```

Now everything works, and I have a panic handler in C that shows where the error occurred!

Comment: error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
 --> src/sum.rs:2:1
  |
2 | #![feature(lang_items, libc)]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0522]: definition of an unknown language item: `panic_fmt`
  --> src/sum.rs:13:1
   |
13 | #[lang="panic_fmt"]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ definition of unknown language item `panic_fmt`

and many other errors